# How to to use the dynamically generated label value in a ahref link in JSP?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

Below are the labels in my jsp page:-

```
<label id="latitude"></label>
<label id="longitude"></label>
```

Values are dynamically allocated to the above Id from a JSON Array:-

```
var jsonArray=JSON.parse(response.trim());
                    VehclDetails =jsonArray;
                    for(i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++)
                    {
                       var obj=jsonArray[i];
                       $("#latitude").html(obj.Latitude);
                       $("#longitude").html(obj.Longitude);
                    }
```

latitude and longitude are the label id which i had declared in my jsp page. I want this values to be passed to a new html link, below is my html link:-

```
<td><a href= "https://www.google.co.in/?= latitude +,+ longitude #q= latitude +,+ longitude " target="_blank">Click</a></td>
```

How to pass the latitude and longitude values to above link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the anchor tag href in client side. Below are the simple steps to achieve this.

1) Add a ID to your anchor tag.

```
<td><a id="AnchorID" href="" target="_blank">Click</a></td>
```

2) Update the link from script.

```
$('#AnchorID').attr('href','https://www.google.co.in/?=latitude=" + latitude + "longitude="+ longitude);
```

According to your need it will be similar to below:

```
var jsonArray=JSON.parse(response.trim());
VehclDetails =jsonArray;
for(i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++)
{
var obj=jsonArray[i];
$("#latitude").html(obj.Latitude);
$("#longitude").html(obj.Longitude);
$('#AnchorID').attr('href','https://www.google.co.in/?=latitude=" + latitude + "longitude="+ longitude);
}
```

In the above example i built a simple url with latitude and longitude. You can update it as per your need.

Comment: There was some error in the link you provided. have to use the "obj.Longitude" in the link. however it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to assign an onclick event to to your A tag and access both latitude and longitude in Javascript method.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="htmllink">Click</a>

$(function() {
    $("#htmllink").click(function() {
        var latitude = $("#latitude").html();
        var longitude = $("#longitude").html();
        var url = 'https://www.google.co.in/?=' + latitude + ',' + longitude;

        /*
        To replace existing page, call window.location(url);
        To open a new Tab, call window.open(url);
        Update the url accordingly
        */
    });
});
```

Comment: But how to use this variable inside the html link? my link is:- "https://www.google.co.in/?= latitude +,+ longitude #q= latitude +,+ longitude "  where i have to replace the latitude and longitude with variables. how to do that?

Comment: I have given step by step approach to achieve this. see the below Answer.

Comment: @jasim: Please take a read at jQuery documentation before doing web development. You need to put the whole jQuery function in a <script> tag.

Comment: @Wilts C, Its all done properly. am not so new to programming